# call procedure Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a PL/SQL procedure like here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45016/dynamic-oracle-pivot-in-clause

Now I want to use the procedure as the Source for a Report. I am using Oracle Apex 4.0.

When I write it like this:

```
Declare
   x refcursor;
begin
   dynamic_pivot(x);
end;
```

The following error occurs:

> ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH

However, it is possible to use a Procedure as the source as described here:
[Calling procedure in oracle apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572614/calling-procedure-in-oracle-apex)

Comment: An Oracle apex report can only be based on a SQL query, or on a PL/SQL function body returning a SQL query. For the latter, your anonymous block must RETURN a string which contains the query to execute.

Comment: The question you linked to doesn't demonstrate anything to do with Apex reports.

Comment: I think what you may want to do is change `dynamic_pivot` into a function that returns a VARCHAR2, not a ref cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a PL/SQL Procedure as a source for an interactive Report.
What you can do is creating a function which you use inside your SELECT Query.
E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE YOUR_FUNCTION(PARM1,PARM2);
```

The definition may look like this:

```
create or replace function your_function
(
 PARM1 in integer,
 PARM2 in integer
) 
return holiday_tab pipelined
as
 v_easter_day date;
begin
...
end;
```

For more on pipelined take a look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#CHDJEGHC

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select region type PL/SQL dynamic content.
Then call a database procedure--

```
declare
   vname number;
begin
   R_MENU(vname );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**// call oracle procedure in php**
$return = parent::sql("call MIGRATION_MO('".$variable1."','".$variable2."')", false);

**// call oracle function in php**
$return = parent::sql("SELECT MIGRATION('".$variable1."','".$variable2."') AS STATUS FROM DUAL", false);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).